# RegEx to allow 9 numbers but block any more than 4 duplicate numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for assistance with finding a RegEx to require exactly 9 numbers but block any more than 4 duplicate numbers in a row. If more or less than 9 characters are entered it should fail.

Examples would be:

- 123456789 - **allowed**
- 111156789 - **allowed**
- 121314151 - **allowed**
- 111116789 - **not allowed**
- 123499999 - **not allowed**

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
/^(?!.*(\d)\1{5})(\d{9})*$/
```

Comment: Can you add the regex that you've tried?

Comment: Can you clarify if 121314151 should pass or fail?
 Also what should happen if more than 9 numbers are found?

Comment: Thanks, additional details added.

Comment: It will be easier to do this in two regexes. `/^\d{9}$/` should match and `/(\d)\1{3}/` should fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Block any digit, that repeats 5 times in row:
`/^(?:(\d)(?!\1{4})){9}$/`

Explanation:

`(\d)` - first group, that matches any digit.
`\1` - repeats first group contents.
`(\d)(?!\1{4})` - block digit, that have 4 same digits after it.
`(?:(\d)(?!\1{4})){9}` - match only 9 of this patterns (each contain only one digit)

Example:

```
let reg = /^(?:(\d)(?!\1{4})){9}$/;

console.log(reg.test("123456789"));  // -> true
console.log(reg.test("111116789"));  // -> false
console.log(reg.test("12345678"));   // -> false
console.log(reg.test("1234567890")); // -> false
```

Comment: From the question `111156789 - allowed`, so, despite the less than clear wording, they want to _allow_ 4 in a row, but block 5. So you need just one more `\1`

Comment: While this solution was posted and stayed incorrect, I saw 5 upvotes on this. And after this solution was edited to make it correct, there are no upvotes anymore? I am seriously wondering what upvoters saw that made them upvote this so quickly? Also Matt Burland made a comment too for correcting the solution, did upvoters didn't even care to read the first comment by Matt? Normally when someone posts an incorrect solution, I see many downvotes on it but not here. And I mean no offense for kerrytazi and wish him to get tons of upvotes on his answers/posts.

Comment: Jeez the answer was effectively complete.

Comment: @kerrytazi thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`/(?=(?!(\d)\1{4}))^\d{9}$/`

Explanation:

`(\d)\1{4}` - 5 repeating digits of the same number

`(?!(\d)\1{4})` - Don't match 5 of the same number

`(?=(?!(\d)\1{4}))` - Make sure the expression doesn't include 5 digits of the same number, then return to the original starting point for further matching

`^\d{9}$` - Match an expression that is 9 digits total

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex, which rejects the match, ONLY IF, any digit is repeated at least 5 times.

```
/^(?!\d*(\d)\1{4})\d{9}$/
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `(?!\d*(\d)\1{4})` --> Negative look ahead, that rejects the match if any digit in the string is repeated at least five times.
- `\d{9}` --> Matches exactly nine digits
- `$` --> End of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXAlYw/1)

Here is a javascript code for same,

```js
let regex = /^(?!\d*(\d)\1{4})\d{9}$/;
var strs = ["123456789","111156789","121314151","111116789","123499999","888888888","199999991","123327333"];

for (var i=0;i<strs.length;i++) {
    console.log(strs[i] + " --> " + regex.test(strs[i]));
}
```